# How to sort a CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Tags: java, copyonwritearraylist

I want to sort `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. But the following code is throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```java
public class CopyOnWriteArrayListExample {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
     List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
     list.add("3");
     list.add("2");
     list.add("1");

     Collections.sort(list);
  }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1049)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:159)
    at com.sac.list.CopyOnWriteArrayListExample.main(CopyOnWriteArrayListExample.java:15)
```

How can I sort a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`?

Comment: I suspect the stack trace is longer than that - showing the operation that failed...

Comment: I suggest copy it to ArrayList, sort and copy back.

Comment: Yes , stack trace is longer . Let me edit and put a full trace.

Comment: @talex- This would lead be quite a costly operation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Collections.sort uses ListIterator.set

```
    ...
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set((T)a[j]);
    }
```

but CopyOnWriteArrayList's ListIterator does not support the remove, set or add methods.

Workaround:

```
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        list.set(i, (String) a[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Evgeniy's solution points in the right way, but `list.set(i, (String) a[i])` has to gain the lock on `list` for each element in the list. If there is a concurrent thread which writes into `list` this will slow down the loop dramatically.

To minimize blocking it's better to reduce the number of statements which alter `list`:

```
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    // ... fill list with values ...

    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    temp.addAll(list);                           
    Collections.sort(temp);

    list.clear();            // 1st time list is locked
    list.addAll(temp);       // 2nd time list is locked
```

The downside is that if a concurrent thread reads `list` between `clear()` and `addAll(temp)` it will see an empty list wheras with Evgeniy's solution it may see a partially sorted list.

Answer (score 6):

In JDK1.8 can use `sort(Comparator<? super E> c)` directly.

```java
List<Integer> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(3);
list.add(4);
list.add(1);

list.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1 - o2;
    }
});
```

Comment: This needs minSDK 24

Comment: Note that on Java 8, the `Collections.sort` method used in the question would also work, since as of Java 8 it delegates to [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)): "This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method using the specified list and comparator."

Answer (score 1):

Because a CopyOnWriteArrayList copies itself every time you change it, its Iterator doesn't allow you to make changes the list. If it did, the Iterator would not be thread safe, and thread safety is the whole point of this class. `Collections.sort()` won't work as it requires an Iterator that supports the `set()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 8, the given code works without exception.

In versions of Java prior to 8, `Collections.sort` used [`ListIterator.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)) on the given list's `ListIterator`, forwarding any `UnsupportedOperationException` thrown by that method.  [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)'s `ListIterator` always throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when the `set` method is called.

**`CopyOnWriteArrayList`**

> Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (`remove`, `set`, and `add`) are not supported. These methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Starting with Java 8, [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) delegates to the newly-added [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method.  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` overrides this method with a custom implementation that works with it.  Therefore, the Java 8 version of `Collections.sort` successfully sorts the list, rather than throwing an exception as it did in prior versions of Java.

**`Collections.sort`**

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> This implementation defers to the [`List.sort(Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method using the specified list and comparator.