# Why does Collections.sort(List) work in Java 8 with CopyOnWriteArrayList but not in Java 7?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-7

I can sort a list of users without any problems using the following code and Java 8:

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<User> allCurrentLoginnedUsersList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>(); 
Collections.sort(allCurrentLoginnedUsersList);
```

Now, I changed to Java 7 and I saw no errors on eclipse. But now, when running under Java 7 I got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList$COWIterator.set(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:1049)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:221)
    at com.fluent.User.sortAllCurrentLoginnedUsers(User.java:446)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There was a change between Java 7 (and early version of Java 8) and Java 8u20 in the way `Collections.sort` work ([issue 8032636](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8032636), as noted by [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)).

---

Java 7 [`Collections.sort(list, c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) specifies that:

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n² log(n) performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in place.

[Looking at the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29), this is done by obtaining a `ListIterator` from the list. However, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` [`listIterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#listIterator%28%29) method states that the iterator returned does not support the `set` operation:

> The returned iterator provides a snapshot of the state of the list when the iterator was constructed. No synchronization is needed while traversing the iterator. **The iterator does NOT support the `remove`, `set` or `add` methods**.

This explains the error you are getting when running your code with Java 7. As a workaround, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28805283/1743880) where the answer is to dump the content of the list into an array, sort the array and put the elements back in the list.

---

In Java 8, [`Collections.sort(list, c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) changed implementation:

> This implementation defers to the `List.sort(Comparator)` method using the specified list and comparator.

And the new method [`CopyOnWriteArrayList.sort(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) (introduced in Java 8) does not use the list iterator so it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.sort()`, in Java 7 (and early versions of Java 8) uses the list iterator's `set()` to modify the list. But CopyOnWriteArrayList's iterator is explicitly documented as not supporting this operation.

How to fix it? Transform your `CopyOnWriteArrayList` into a regular ArrayList or array, sort that, and then clear the CopyOnWriteArrayList and fill it again with the sorted list.

I strongly suggest to make your comparator much simpler by using `Integer.compare()` and `Boolean.compare()`.

Comment: It's not luck, `Collections.sort` changed implementation in Java 8 :)

Comment: Strange. I don't see that change in my version of the source code of Java 8. Maybe it's too old. In my version (1.8.0-b132), List.sort() calls Collections.sort().

Comment: Ah, that's weird indeed. [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29) shows the change though.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 the implementation of `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` has been changed to now redirect to a [new `sort` method in the `List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). The default implementation of that `sort` method seems to be the previous behaviour (i.e. using `List.listIterator()`, which would still fail with an `UnsupportedOperationException`), but the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` explicitly provides a different version which does not use an `Iterator`:

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") E[] es = (E[])newElements;
        Arrays.sort(es, c);
        setArray(newElements);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```