# Difference between Collections.sort(list) and list.sort(Comparator)

Tags: java, list, sorting

Is there any reason why I should prefer `Collections.sort(list)` method over simply calling the `list.sort()`? Internally `Collections.sort` merely calls the `sort` method of the `List` class anyway.

It's just surprising that almost everyone is telling me to use `Collections.sort`. Why?

Comment: list.sort() could not be introduced until default methods were made available on interfaces in java 8

Comment: I fail to see why list.sort could not be introduced without default methods.

Comment: @emory Before default method support was added, introducing a new method to an interface would break every existing implementation of the interface.

Comment: I don't want to be picky, however, you can't use `list.sort()` as it requires an argument. So if you prefer to take List's sort, you need to write `list.sort(null)`. Then everybody reading your code wonders, what `null`means -> natural order. For reasons of simplicity and readability I would stick to `Collections.sort(list)` if you use natural ordering. IMHO

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The method [`List.sort(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) that you are refering to was introduced in Java 8, whereas the utility method [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) has been there since Java 1.2.

As such, you will find a lot of reference on the Internet mentioning that utility method but that's just because it has been in the JDK for a lot longer.

Note that the change in implementation for `Collections.sort` [was made in 8u20](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34827492/1743880).

Answer (score 12):

This is simply a change to the APIs.  With a language with such wide spread adoption as Java, what typically happens is for a period of time, the older method is preferable, to maintain legacy support.

After this period of time, the older API becomes deprecated (or perhaps not, both can remain in place indefinitely).  Within this time period improvements may be made to the new API causing its functionality to diverge slightly from the original implementation, encouraging developers to adopt it.  The requirements/results of the new API may diverge slightly, and the implementation may change dramatically.

Then, eventually, the new API takes over, and the older API is no longer required and removed.  In a language with as wide of adoption as Java this can take years, or decades.  Developers can have a plan to remove an API, but be forced to leave it in by the community.

Comment: Sun was notoriously keen about keeping backward compatibility.  This is what allows 20 year old code to run unchanged on modern JVM's.

Answer (score 10):

The simple answer is that `Collections.sort` delegates to `List.sort`. Since one call delegate to the other there are equivalent. However, it is preferable to use `List.sort` to simply avoid the extra method call.