# How do you sort WritableList in Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How do you sort WritableList? I tried using sort method but It gave me an unsupported operation exception

Sample code:

```
writableList.sort( (o1, o2) -> o1.getPath().compareTo( o2.getPath() ) );
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.list.ObservableList$2.set(ObservableList.java:250)
at java.util.List.sort(List.java:482)
```

Iterator's set method from ObservableList:

```
@Override
public void set(E o) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`WritableList` implements `java.util.List`.  The reason you are getting this exception is mentioned in [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-)

> UnsupportedOperationException - if the list's list-iterator does not support the set operation

You can see the implementation of WritableList's `iterator` [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.0/org.eclipse.core.databinding/observable/1.4.1/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/list/ObservableList.java#ObservableList.iterator%28%29)

You need to use `Collections.sort(writableList);`

Comment: What change does it make if I use the Collections.sort?

     public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
        list.sort(c);
    }

Comment: Please read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910841/difference-between-collection-sortlist-and-list-sort). In my opinion your 'WritableList' might not be using Java8.