# New sort method added in List after using Collections.sort

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

Why is a new sort method added in `java.util.List` in java 8 when we have a provision to sort lists using `Collections.sort`

Comment: your question is same as your explanation, please improve your explanation.

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth what do you want more exactly ? OP can't give you an explanation on a theorical question.

Comment: @Shuchita check this question answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910841/difference-between-collection-sortlist-and-list-sort

Comment: @Kailas Thanks for providing this link

Answer (score 29):

1. because it makes the API more intuitive and OO
2. because it allows implementations of List to use a faster sorting algorithm, best suited to their internal structure. For example, ArrayList can sort its internal array without first doing a copy as the default implementation does.

Comment: Overriding methods may not only be faster, they may enforce additional guarantees. E.g. before Java 8, applying `Collections.sort` to a `synchronizeList` or `Vector` was not safe without additional manual synchronization. Today, it delegates to `List.sort` and these collections override it with a `synchronized` method… Further, unmodifiable lists can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` unconditionally, even if the `sort` attempt would not result in an actual change.

Comment: @Holger I knew about the second one, interesting enough I find it correct (I know I'm asking for trouble here), but my gut is saying that instead of potentially sort and check if sort has changed anything or not, simply throwing the exception is more idiomatic; unless a check against `SortedSet` would be performed for example...

Comment: @Eugene it doesn’t make any sense to check a `List` against `SortedSet`; it’s impossible to implement both contracts correctly in one class. Further, I doubt that anyone is doing an explicit check whether sorting changed anything, that just happens implicitly, e.g. `Collections.sort(Collections.<String>emptyList())` does not fail, likewise  `Collections.emptyList().addAll(Collections.emptyList())` does nothing. Perhaps, that has been kept for compatibility. Newer constructs, e.g. `Collections.sort(List.<String>of())` or `List.of().addAll(List.of());` do the idiomatic unconditional throwing.

Comment: @Holger Yes, the old behavior of zero elements to an empty (and unmodifiable) list is kept for compatibility. This allows latent bugs in applications, because this "works" until somebody tries to add a non-zero number of elements, at which time it blows up. The newer implementations provide a more "fail-fast" behavior. The new `sort` default method also can provide fail-fast behavior, as you observed. The old `Collections.sort` algorithm, if called on an unmodifiable list, would copy out, do the sort, and **then** blow up when copying back to the original list.

Comment: @Holger This also has a perhaps unfortunate side effect, which is that `Collections.sort` is now no longer failure idempotent. That is, if the sort fails -- for example, if there is a bug in the comparison method resulting in an exception -- sorting in-place can leave the original list corrupted. That didn't occur with the old copy-sort-copy-back technique.

Comment: @StuartMarks it did if an exception occurred in the middle of copying them back.

Comment: @StuartMarks that’s a trade-off I can live with. After all, a broken comparator can corrupt the list anyway, e.g. if no exception has been thrown, which was more likely before the introduction of TimSort, so we don’t loose much compared to the old behavior (depending on how deep we dig). Being “failure idempotent” is a nice-to-have but shouldn’t sacrifice the performance of correct code in a significant amount.

Comment: @OrangeDog Sure, but an exception occurring during copy-back is almost unheard of. In most cases it doesn't even allocate memory, so even OOME is unlikely. It's still possible of course. However, exceptions thrown from the comparison method are quite likely, as you can tell from SO questions on this topic (search for "comparison method violates its general contract").

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your thoughts on this. There is actually a bug on this, but so far we haven't felt the impetus to fix it.

Answer (score 16):

[JB Nizet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49664858/2513200) already gives you reasons why it was a good idea to add this method. The second aspect of this is:

If it is so obviously a good idea to add this method, why hasn't it been added in some earlier version?

Both the `List` interface and the static utility `Collections` were added in the same version 1.2, so it would have been possible to include it from the start.

After that opportunity had been missed, there was no way to add it any more. Adding a method to an interface was a change that would have broken backward-compatibility prior to the introduction of `default`-methods in Java 1.8.

Comment: Nice one, as nice as figuring that bug 199 on that other question ;-)