# What is the most efficient way to sort an array in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Which of the two Java sorting methods, Collections.sort(list) or list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder()), is more efficient?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 1));
    
//1.Collections
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);// [1, 2, 3]

    
//2.import java.util.Comparator;
list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
System.out.println(list);// [1,2,3]
```

I expect that there won't be a significant performance difference when comparing the algorithms of these two methods.

Comment: `Collections.sort` calls `List#sort` passing it `null` - so both the same ‍♂️

Comment: Seems it was discussed already here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910841/difference-between-collections-sortlist-and-list-sortcomparator

Comment: It's _perhaps marginally_ more efficient to use `list.sort`, because `Collections.sort(list)` calls `list.sort()`; so you avoid one function call in the worst case, and no difference if the JIT optimized that function call away.

Comment: Actually, you're sorting lists, not arrays.  So use `Arrays.sort()` for arrays.  Unfortunately, `Arrays.sort()` does not take a comparator for primitive arrays.  So you're stuck with natural ordering.